# Is there a way filter only selected tags in Django-bleach?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Im trying to use Django-ckeditor with Django-bleach, but Im running into problems where Django-bleach would filter all the tags that Django-ckeditor uses. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bleach is an allowed-list-based HTML sanitizing library that escapes or strips markup and attributes.

To configure the allowed tags, you could set the `BLEACH_ALLOWED_TAGS` in your django settings or specify the `allowed_tags` parameter on your models `BleachField`.

For more information: https://django-bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#configuring-bleach